# Algorithm for solving a shortest edges problem?

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm

Here is the problem:
For a graph of several nodes, each node could only connect to one of the other nodes. How to minimize the total edges of this graph?
[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8uRm.png)[Fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih13C.png)

As the above, Fig.2 has shorter length than that of Fig.1. Is there an algorithm to calculate the shortest length of the total edges?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is called 'minimum weight perfect matching'. [Kolmogorov, V. - Blossom V: A new implementation of
a minimum cost perfect matching algorithm](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/blossom5.pdf) presents an efficient algorithm. The C++ implementation of the algorithm in the paper [is available](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software/blossom5-v2.05.src.tar.gz) (retrieved from [here](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html); the link given in the paper itself is no longer active).

A cursory Google search suggested that various graph processing libraries ( like LEDA ) include an algorithm for solving your problem in their toolbox.

***Caveat***

I have not tested the implementation of the cited paper and do not know about the legal status of using it.

Comment: Really appreciate for your detailed and perfect answer.